# Mostrar Json en php

Tags: php, json

Tengo este json

```
[
  {
     "productID":"10",
     "Name": "camisa"
  },
  {
     "productID":"20",
     "Name": "pantalon"
  }
]
```

quiero hacer que se muestre el nombre de todos los productos y su id correspondiente, pero no se muestra ninguno. 
Así es como lo tengo

```
$info = json_decode($response);
echo "<h2>$info->Name</h2>";
```

$reponse es donde esta el json.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: puedes hacerlo `$info = json_decode($response,true);
echo "<h2>$info[0]['Name']</h2>";`

Comment: deberia estar en **$info[0]->Name**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es decodificar como array el JSON, para esto solo hay que agregar un parámetro mas a la función `json_decode` como lo dice su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

> assoc:
>
> Cuando es TRUE, los object devueltos serán convertidos a array asociativos.

Al final tu código queda algo así:

```
$info = json_decode($response, true);
```

Ahora tu variable `$info` contiene un array asociativo, ya puedes extraer los valores con un `foreach()` de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($info as $elemento){
    echo ($elemento["productID"]);
    echo ($elemento["Name"]);
    echo ("<br/>");//Solo para salto de linea
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si haces un print_r($info) te entrega lo siguiente:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => 10 [Name] => camisa ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => 20 [Name] => pantalon ) )
```

al ser un json obtienes una colección de datos por lo tanto  **debes indicar el indice**, ej:

```
echo $info[0]->Name;
```

según algún criterio deberías recorrer estos nodos y acceder a cada uno de ellos para poder obtener el valor del conjunto de datos.
Prueba con eso.

Saludos.

Comment: para mostrar todos los nombres como? porque así solo me muestra un nombre

Comment: con un foreach  por ejemplo. eso te soluciona todo tu problema.